# Refund went through AFTER I received my current statement?

Tags: credit-card, minimum-payment, balance

So I bought a blender from Wal-Mart for $100. I returned it a couple days later. My current credit card statement came in the mail and shows the $100 blender was bought. It does not show the refund. I called the credit card company and they told me the refund went through and it will show up on my next statement. My current balance (with the $100 blender) is $300 (min payment $80).

So my question is, should I pay $200 or should I pay the full $300? I don't want any interest or penalties, etc.

EDIT: I called the credit card company and they told me my current balance was $200 on their system and that I could pay $200, not $300 without getting penalized.

Comment: If you don't pay the full $300 they'll charge you interest.

Answer (score 2):

You should pay the amount shown on the statement, i.e., the full $300.  The statement shows what you owe based on the state of the account at the time the statement was issued.  Since the refund didn't go through until after the statement was issued, the refund isn't germane to this statement.  Assuming the refund did go through, it will reduce your *next* payment by $100.

Comment: Does this apply if the refund comes through between the statement issue date and the due date?

Comment: I called the credit card company and they told me my current balance was $200 on their system and that I could pay $200, not $300 without getting penalized.

Comment: If you have any new charges, there's a chance you see some interest charged. I'm not saying it *will* happen , just it wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 1):

The $100 refund is a prepayment towards your next statement. Is the current balance (not the statement) balance less than 300? If it is and you are paying online, then you generally will be limited to paying no more than the current balance.

Comment: I called the credit card company and they said in their system, they received the $100 refund and that my account, as of today, I owe $200?

Comment: Then you have a good one that took the refund as a partial payment of the current balance. If they say you only owe $200, then that is what you owe.